# Is it possible to find a basis for a non-compact operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Is it possible to find a basis for a non-compact operator?

I was thinking of applying the spectral theorem to non-compact operators.

Comment: There's no such thing as "an orthonormal basis for an operator". Are you instead asking about an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this wiki page notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Possible_absence_of_eigenvectors), there is no guarantee that a (self-adjoint) non-compact operator has *any* eigenvectors, let alone enough to form a basis (orthonormal or otherwise).  In particular, the multiplication operator $A:L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$ defined by $[A\phi](t) = t\phi(t)$ has no eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

The spectral theorem for self-adjoint (or more generally hermitian) operators in Hilbert spaces is a standard topic in functional analysis.  It will occupy a prominent place in almost any functional analysis textbook.  But you can't use eigenvectors.  Rather, standard formulation are in terms of projection-valued measures (resolutions of the identity), or the continuous functional calculus.